# Transform String into xml object for Request

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I need integrate with a system with this WSDL:
[wsdl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Muv.png)

In Studio, I use "Web Service Consumer". The problem is in the body. IN transform I create the payload, but i only get it to work if i hardcode it; I can't make the string dynamic

This script works but it uses fixed literal strings:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://test.es/IC/SERVICE/
---
{
    ns0#wsImprXML: {
        ns0#DataXML: "
                    <root>
                        <exp>
                            <bult>
                                <ci>965</ci> 
                                <nif>123</nif> 
                                <ccc>36020</ccc>
                                <service>31</service> 
                                <product>2</product> 
                                <total>1</total> 
                                <price>10,6</price> 
                            </bult>
                        </exp>
                    </root>",
        ns0#OptionsXML: "<wsOptionsXML>
                                <VersionDataXML>1.0.0</VersionDataXML>
                                <VersionOptionsXML>1.0.0</VersionOptionsXML>
                                <VersionResponseXML>1.1.0</VersionResponseXML>
                                <VersionErrorXML>3.2.0</VersionErrorXML> 
                            </wsOptionsXML>"
    }
}
```

How can I create the string inside the body of the xml? This string must be dynamic (filling it with values ​​that I have stored in variables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use literal XML. You can easily generate XML dynamically from anything that DataWeave considers an object. I'll give an example with DataWeave variables, that you can replace by Mule variables (`vars.myVar`). Using the [write()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-write) function converts an object into a string as your WSDL requires. You can pass the transformed text, or convert it in place, as I'm showing below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://test.es/IC/SERVICE/
var someText=write(
    {
        root: {
            exp: {
                bult: {
                    ci: 965,
                    nif: 123,
                    ccc: 36020,
                    service: 31,
                    product: 2,
                    total: 1,
                    price: 10.6
                }
            }
        }
    }, "application/xml")
            
 
var someObject= {
        wsOptionsXML: {
            VersionDataXML: "1.0.0",
            VersionOptionsXML: "1.0.0",
            VersionResponseXML: "1.1.0",
            VersionErrorXML:"1.2.0"
        }
    }                    
---
{
    ns0#wsImprXML: {
        ns0#DataXML: someText,
        ns0#OptionsXML: write(someObject,"application/xml")
    }
}
```

Comment: works correctly. Thank you very much crack